# Modify the PAC address of the WiFi network

Tags: android, wifi, pac

I want to modify the PAC address of the WiFi network through the code, how should I do? like this picture,

[image]

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Android 5, there is no automatic proxy settings, after Android 6, non system applications can not be set up by the proxy program